# What do you call a door-attached bar for hanging belts?

Tags: closet, terminology, hanger

Closet doors, particularly those for the closet section which houses a rail with hangers, often have a sort of a cylindrical bar attached to the inside of the door. A thin bar at a short distance from the door, but covering most of its width, on which you hang belts or ties.

My motivation is, as you might have guessed, having a closet which is missing this device and wanting to get one. Hopefully I won't have to settle for something like in the picture.

I was wondering whether this fixture has a name - a single noun or a phrase - that is commonly used.

(*This is actually not such a great example, because what you're seeing here is an IKEA Grundtal bar intended for the kitchen.*)

[image]

Comment: It could be a number of things.  For search terms try Tie rack, Belt rack, Closet organizing bar, Towel bar, belt organizing bar.  You could make one out of pipe or a wood dowel. There are no rules for your closet, come up with something that works best for you.

Comment: @AlaskaMan: I'm not well-enough tooled to make my own. But - I think this comment should be an answer.

Comment: Ok, it is an answer.

Answer (score 3):

It could be a number of things.

For search terms try [Tie rack](https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffsb&q=tie%20rack&iax=images&ia=images), [Belt rack](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=Belt%20rack&t=ffsb&iar=images&iax=images&ia=images), [Towel bar](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=Towel%20bar&t=ffsb&iar=images&iax=images&ia=images), [belt organizing bar](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=belt%20organizing%20bar&t=ffsb&iar=images&iax=images&ia=images).

You could make one out of pipe or a wood dowel.

There are no rules for your closet, come up with something that works best for you. It could be as simple as a piece of wood with some hooks screwed into it. (*have the home center cut the wood to length, not tools needed except to screw it to the wall/closet door*)

[copper pipe towel rack](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=copper%20pipe%20towel%20rack&t=ffsb&iar=images&iax=images&ia=images)